# Vote buttons revert to incorrect state when tapping on "Add comment"

Tags: bug, comments, voting, android-app

When I tap an upvote or downvote button the button turns orange. If I tap on the "Add comment" button on the same post, the vote button reverts to the gray unvoted state.

If I tap again (on the vote button) in 10 minutes, it tells me that I already voted. If I tap again after 10 minutes, it tells me that I already voted more than 10 minutes ago and it's now locked in.

Refreshing the question shows the buttons in the correct state (orange when voted).

This seems to happen after the tabbed model was changes to a single-page model.

* App version <s>1.0.50</s> 1.0.51
* Samsung Galaxy SIII LTE
* Android 4.3

*Also:*

> Same goes when undoing the vote by tapping it again (after the question has been refreshed, of course). Will prompt *"You haven't cast a vote to undo"* - [Andrew T.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/241919/andrew-t)

I reproduced this as well. Basically, you up vote or down vote, then refresh, then undo your vote, then tap on "Add comment" (the vote button reverts to orange), then try to undo the vote again. You will then get the error mentioned.

Comment: Same goes when undoing the vote by tapping it again (after the question has been refreshed, of course). Will prompt *"You haven't cast a vote to undo"*

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks for reporting! Actually it's the same bug inversed. I added the reproduction steps.